# SQL AND after WHERE NOT EXISTS STATEMENT

Tags: mysql

im trying to use an AND in a mysql statement after having used a WHERE NOT EXISTS, but its not working for me, heres where i am with it

```
SELECT * from ".$usertable." u where not exists (select * from ".$usermetatable." m where m.meta_key = 'course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID ) AND m.meta_value = locationvalue";
```

or would i have to add that before the WHERE NOT EXIST?

Comment: There is an unmatched double quotes in your code.

Comment: Ok... probably it is not the cause of the issue

Comment: what's `locationvalue`? Seriously, `it's not working` does not mean anything...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is:

```
SELECT * 
from ".$usertable." u 
where not exists (select * from ".$usermetatable." m where m.meta_key = 'course_progress' and m.user_id = u.ID ) 
AND m.meta_value = locationvalue";
```

You are referencing 'm', but 'm' is enclosed in brackets

It should be something more like:

```
SELECT * 
from ".$usertable." u 
where not exists (select * from ".$usermetatable." where meta_key = 'course_progress' and user_id = u.ID ) m
AND m.meta_value = locationvalue";
```

I wouldn't use as exists on mysql or any subquery if you're worried about performance mysql optimizer is pretty bad at that.

Something like this should work more efficiently (untested and might have a typo):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   ".$usertable." u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from ".$usermetatable." where meta_key = 'course_progress' ) m 
ON  m.user_id = u.ID
AND m.meta_value = u.locationvalue
WHERE m.user_id IS NULL
```